# iOS ShareKit, twitter logout? facebook status empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sharekit

I am using ShareKit plugin for iPhone to enable social sharing for the application I'm working on. I set up everything, I stripped it to have Facebook and Twitter services only, connected successfully to both and now I have 1 problem in each of the services...

The problem with Twitter is how to logout/signout...
ShareKit sends the text and the url to Twitter's publish box. It is saving status perfectly. The question is where to put "logout" button for twitter? I want the iPhone user to logout in order to change username. This is done by calling the method
`[SHKTwitter logout];`.
Now, the problem is where to put the button that will fire this method? In navigationToolbar of Twitter actionSheet I already have 2 buttons and the toolbar (bottom one) is covered by the keyboard?

*[EDIT]: I solved this issue by modifying the twitter action sheet. I resized the textView and then added UIToolbar and changed its position so that it fits into the gap between the keyboard and textView. Into the toolbar I added one button with an action that calls a logoutTwitter method*

Facebook problem is more of a mystery...
 So, in my sharreKitButtonHandler I have the following code:

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com"];

    SHKItem *shareItem = [SHKItem URL:url title:self.itemTitle.text];

    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:shareItem];

    [actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.shareKitToolbar];`

This code prepares some ivars of a shareItem object and in the case of Twitter shareKit manages to fill the status box so that user just needs to press publish and its done...
In the case of Facebook it is not working. FB dialog pops out and the share box is empty saying "What's on your mind?" The url and the title are not put into the publish form?

So, please if you have any clue what's going on in the latter problem or how to solve the former problem, I would really appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0):

It takes five lines to add twitter. I wouldn't bother with Sharekit for that.

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetView = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
[tweetView addImage:imageToShare;
[tweetView addURL:URLToShare]; 
[tweetView setInitialText:messageToShare];
[senderViewController presentViewController:tweetView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I wanted to use sharekit for my projects, but it was difficult to use and after a week I gave up as I couldn't share more than one thing at the same time (URL, Image, Message, etc.) which is pretty useless if you want to promote your app.

Facebook is more difficult, probably a 100 lines. It took me 3-4 days to implement. It will be integrated in iOS 6 just like Twitter :)